# I am not able to get the renderflex to go

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, frontend, widget

I am really new to fluuter.This is my code below. I tried making a profile page but then the bio and other stuff in overflowing and i am not able to get it to be displayed one line below the other.ANy help would be appreciated.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async { Navigator.push(context, PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context,animation1,animation2)=>Homescreen(),transitionDuration: Duration.zero,reverseTransitionDuration: Duration.zero)); return true; },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Profile'),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20),
            child: GNav(
              onTabChange: (index) {
                if (index == 0) {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context,animation1,animation2)=>Homescreen(),transitionDuration: Duration.zero,reverseTransitionDuration: Duration.zero));
                }
                if (index == 1) {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context,animation1,animation2)=>Forum_categories(),transitionDuration: Duration.zero,reverseTransitionDuration: Duration.zero));
                }
                if (index == 2) {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context,animation1,animation2)=>Chatbot(),transitionDuration: Duration.zero,reverseTransitionDuration: Duration.zero));
                }
                if (index == 3) {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context,animation1,animation2)=>Setting(),transitionDuration: Duration.zero,reverseTransitionDuration: Duration.zero));
                }
              },
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              color: Colors.white,
              activeColor: Colors.white,
              tabBorderRadius: 10,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
              tabBackgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 900),
              tabs: const [
                GButton(
                  icon: Icons.home,
                  text: 'Home',
                  gap: 10,
                ),
                GButton(
                  icon: Icons.question_answer,
                  text: 'Forum',
                  gap: 10,
                ),
                GButton(
                  icon: Icons.chat_rounded,
                  text: 'Chatbot',
                  gap: 10,
                ),
                GButton(
                  icon: Icons.settings,
                  text: 'settings',
                  gap: 10,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body:
           SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(

              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 30, 30, 30),
              child: Column(


                children: [
                  imagepicker(
                    onpickedimage: (pickedimage) async {
                      _selectedimage = pickedimage;
                      final storageref = FirebaseStorage.instance
                          .ref()
                          .child('User-images')
                          .child('${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}.jpg');
                      TaskSnapshot snap = await storageref.putData(_selectedimage!);
                      String imageurl = await snap.ref.getDownloadURL();
                      print(imageurl);
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('users')
                          .doc(user.uid)
                          .update({'image_url': imageurl});
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),






                         StreamBuilder(
                          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('users')
                              .doc(user.uid)
                              .snapshots(),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return const Text('Something went wrong');
                            }
                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.waiting) {
                              return const Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              );
                            } else {
                              Map<String, dynamic> doc =
                                  snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                              return Column(
                                children: [Row(children: [const Text('USERNAME:',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),SizedBox(width: 5,),Text(doc['username'],maxLines: 1,),],),

                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Row(children: [const Text('Bio:',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),SizedBox(width: 5,),Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(doc['Bio'],maxLines: 4,overflow: TextOverflow.clip,),
                                    ],
                                  ),],),

                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Row(children: [const Text('Email-Id:',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),SizedBox(width: 5,),Text(doc['email_id'],maxLines: 1,),],),

                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Row(children: [const Text('Company:',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),SizedBox(width: 5,),doc['Company']==null?Text('Add Company name'):Text(doc['Company'],maxLines: 1,),],),

                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),

                                      Row(children: [const Text('Position:',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),SizedBox(width: 5,),doc['Position']==null?Text('Add Position'):Text(doc['Position'],maxLines: 1,),],),



                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Row(mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,children: [const Text('About-Company:',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),SizedBox(width: 5,),doc['About_company']==null?Text('Add Company Information'):Text(doc['About_company'],maxLines: 4,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),],),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ),



                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        signout();
                       // Navigator.of(context).pop();




                      },
                      child: const Text('Logout'))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how to profile page looks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Goh.jpg)

I tried adding an expanded widget around it, i tried giving the text a maxline feature, I tried setting the overflow parameter for the text but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.